# Hover not working on css menu active li class? Works on others?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

I can't seem to get the hover to work on my very first css menu navigation button.  It is an active li class, does anyone have any ideas? The other menu option' hover effect is working just fine. CSS code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
/* Menu CSS */#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;  
}

#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}

li.space1{
    visibility: hidden;
}

li.space2{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #9e3825;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(116, 37, 2, 0.7);
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: url(images/hover.png) repeat;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #97321f;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(122, 42, 26, 0.64);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:active {
  background: url(images/active.png) no-repeat;
}
/* Childs */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 52px;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a {
  padding: 18px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: #393939;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:hover {
  border-left: 4px solid #de553b;
  background: url(images/hover.png) repeat;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:active {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
}

#Table_01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:1px;
    width:864px;
    height:1px;
    visibility: inherit;
}


#DropDown-Design2-11 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:50px;
    width:347px;
    height:166px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-12 {
    position:absolute;
    left:347px;
    top:50px;
    width:103px;
    height:142px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-13 {
    position:absolute;
    left:450px;
    top:50px;
    width:223px;
    height:166px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-14 {
    position:absolute;
    left:673px;
    top:50px;
    width:191px;
    height:166px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-15 {
    position:absolute;
    left:347px;
    top:192px;
    width:103px;
    height:24px;
}
```

Comment: I tried to copy your code into a fiddle and hover seems to be working on every menu option. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/xo430tm0/.

Comment: This is some very, VERY messy code.  I would STRONGLY suggest you clean this up and rewrite it.  

You should post your code in a JSFiddle so people can view and edit it.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I should clarify -- the drop-down menu is working, yes; however the graphic that appears when you actually hover over the menu items doesn't work on the very first one; in this case "Projects"

Comment: Sorry, I really can't see any graphic nor anything different in any of the other menu options when comparing with the 'Projects' option. Could you see if the fiddle that I linked actually does everything you suppose it should?

Comment: I see. I didn't expect the code you posted to be so incomplete, so I really couldn't reproduce any of this in the fiddle. Anyway, from what I can see in the screenshots, you mean that the first menu option doesn't change to light gray when hovered, which happens to all other menu options, right? This is probably due to something very simple to solve, but it is for sure in another CSS file other than the one you pasted.

Comment: edit -- okay now look, I re copy & pasted to make sure it was all there. This is literally all my code for this project, there is nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xo430tm0/2/)**

If you need mouse over effect for active state then use hover for active `li` like this:

CSS:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,#cssmenu > ul > li:hover.active > a {
    background:#000 url(images/hover.png) repeat;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #97321f;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(122, 42, 26, 0.64);
}
```